# Jenkinsfile method being implicitly executed

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

There is an odd `Jenkinsfile` pattern [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabric8io/jenkins-pipeline-library/b53a72ee6af055a25237fc27b63c12b09d3f281f/vars/promoteArtifacts.groovy):

```
def call(body) {
  // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
  def config = [:]
  body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  body.delegate = config
  body()
  // ...
}
```

As far as I can tell, the `call` function is not being directly called elsewhere in the program. How is Groovy executing it?

Comment: I'm guessing it is being `load`ed first in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In groovy there's a concept called implicit call, have a look at the example:

```
class C {
    def call(whatever) {
        println whatever
    }
}

def c = new C()
c(1)
```

The method in `Jenkinsfile` you provided is invoked in the exactly same way. See [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/09/groovy-goodness-using-implicit-call.html) as well.